# How can I join two tables apropreately in (My)SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I need to join two tables together. I know, that there's a JOIN in MySQL, but those results I've got weren't that good for my purpose.

```
Example: 
Say, I have two tables:
a = 
{[1, 2]} 
{[3, 4]} 

b = 
{[5, 6]} 
{[7, 8]}
```

When I now join them using the JOIN-command in MySQL, the result is somewhat like that:

```
result = 
{[1, 2], [5, 6]}  
{[3, 4], [5, 6]}  
{[1, 2], [7, 8]}  
{[1, 2], [7, 8]}
```

but what I need is something like

```
result =  
{[1, 2], [5, 6]} 
{[3, 4], [7, 8]}
```

If anyone has any idea how to do that with a rather simple SQL-script, I would be very thankful :D

Greetings :)

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: You can go through the MySQL UNION concept to solve this problem.

Comment: There does not appear to be anything to join on - so whats the logic for {[1, 2], [5, 6]} in the desired output?

Comment: indeed .. @P.Salmon , because of the bad formatting not sure it looks like the topicstarter seams to more looking for `UNION` or a pivot (to convert records into columns) method not sure which one ..

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for help into providing better formatting and or for providing better example data .. note that there is a [ascii table generator tool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) which can help you

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. In code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. PS Please show what you can do. PS Tables have no order, query results have order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a `join` key.  You seem to want the data "side-by-side".

You can do this using `row_number()` to generate a `join` key:

```
select a.*, b.*
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over () as seqnum
      from a
     ) a join
     (select b.*,
             row_number() over () as seqnum
      from b
     ) b
     on a.seqnum = b.seqnum;
```

Note:  This is not guaranteed to preserve the ordering of the rows in the tables.  It will just put the values side-by-side.

In older versions, you can use variables for this purpose:

select a.*, b.*
from (select a.*, (@rna := @rna + 1) as seqnum
      from a cross join
           (select @rna := 0) params
     ) a join
     (select b.*, (@rnb := @rnb + 1) as seqnum
      from b cross join
           (select @rnb := 0) params
     ) b
     on a.seqnum = b.seqnum;